# Overriding transfer rate limit while using WebClient to download files

Tags: c#, webclient

I am using `WebClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync()` to download files from a website concurrently. For each file, the first x number of bytes downloads at my connection's maximum speed but then slows to a painful 32kbps, causing anything larger than a couple megabytes to take forever to complete. It makes no difference if I'm downloading 1 file or 50.

Is there any way to get around this and have the whole file download without slowing down?

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    wc.Proxy = null;
    wc.DownloadProgressChanged += (s, e) => 
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
        {
            track.Progress = e.ProgressPercentage;
            track.TotalBytes = e.TotalBytesToReceive;
            track.BytesReceived = e.BytesReceived;
        }));

    await wc.DownloadFileTaskAsync(
        new Uri(track.FilePath), 
        string.Format(
            "{0}/{1} {2}.mp3",
            directory,
            track.Number,
            track.TitlePath));
}
```

---

**Update:** The files exhibit the same behavior when loaded into a browser so it would seem that this problem isn't local to my application. If anybody has any ideas as to what might be causing this, please let me know.

---

**Update:** This seems to be an issue with the website I'm using. Downloads from other websites go at full speed and I tried running the program while connected to a VPN with the same results. All of `WebClient`'s data-grabbing methods behave the same, including OpenRead. Are there any tricks that I could try that might prevent the speed from dropping?

Comment: just for grins.  try commenting out your event handler and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Without the event handler I'm unable to see the exact transfer speed, but I didn't notice a difference. It still takes much longer than it should.

Comment: Sounds like it may be more related to your Internet Service Provider than the code itself.  I see no reason why this code would throttle a download. take one of the urls and pop it into your browser.  see if the same thing happens.

Comment: Hmm, I get the same behavior in the browser; the first bit loads very quickly and then slows down drastically. I think the solution to this problem if there is one is probably out of the scope of C#... If anybody has any ideas or can point me in the right direction, I would love to find a way to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

As a point of interest, generally events on asynchronous operations automatically marshal back to the same thread in which the operation was invoked.  so, if you invoked `DownloadFileTaskAsync` on the main GUI thread (or the dispatcher thread, depending on your point of view) then `DownloadProgressChanged` will be invoked on the main GUI thread and you don't need to use `BeginInvoke`.

I don't think that's your problem, but one thing that `WebClient` does do is use thread pool threads to help invoke the events.  Unfortunately, this can often cause stress on the thread pool which ends up with throttling issues with the download.

If throughput *during* the download isn't completely vital, I'd suggest using [`HttpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) instead.

Comment: Thanks for the tip regarding `BeginInvoke`; as it turns out that wasn't necessary at all. Unfortunately, though, using `HttpClient` didn't seem to make any noticeable difference.

Comment: Yep, for some reason I didn't see your comment about the same type of throughput in the browser...